# How to manage my firewall with new Centos's utilities?

Tags: unix, centos, firewall, iptables

I just installed a Centos7 distribution on my server.

I came from Centos6, and I read that `iptables` utility has been replaced by `firewalld` and `services` utility by `systemctl`.

So I try to get my firewall status (`systemctl status firewalld`) but I get following output:

```
● firewalld.service
Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)
Active: inactive (dead)
```

If I try `systemctl status iptables` I get the same output:

```
● iptables.service
Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)
Active: inactive (dead)
```

Can I deduce that my firewall is down? To check it I launch an old `iptables -P OUTPUT DROP` command : my ssh connection doesn't respond anymore (without having restarted any services).

So iptable seems to be running, but how can I manage it if it's not detected by `systemctl`? (for instance to save my configuration). And does it make sense that firewalld was not the default firewall installed?

**Update 1:**

- `journalctl -u firewalld.service` gives no result (only start and stop log's datetime), `journalctl -u iptables.service` too.
- The only occurence about firewall I found in journalctl is : `Feb 22 19:48:49 myhostname.host.net kernel: Bridge firewalling registered`. I don't know about *bridge firewalling*...
- We previously see that adding a rule to iptables was imediatly taken in account without restarting any service (very strange isn't it?), and if I run a `ps aux | grep iptables` command I should get the iptables process, but I get nothing. I really wonder what kind of firewall is running...

Comment: Strange. I recently installed 3 CentOS 7 servers (2 with GUI, 1 without) and all of them have the firewalld running and the iptables not running. Could you run  `journalctl -u firewalld.service` to see if the firewall tries to start at least? What kind of install did you perform?

Comment: @Zina My install is provided by my host (it's a VPS), but it should be a minimalist install, so I expect default Centos' configuration. I update my question with some more informations.

Comment: Searching the net I found [this](http://serverfault.com/questions/710076/centos-7-firewall-cmd-not-found). Seems that you have to install firewalld as the image provided is probably also a stripped down one. One of my installations was a minimal with networking enabled and it has the firewalld service.

Answer (score 0):

Your output is showing `Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)` for both firewalld and iptables.  This probably means that you don't have either installed.

The firewalld package contains the file `/usr/lib/systemd/system/firewalld.service`.  The iptables-services package contains the file `/usr/lib/systemd/system/iptables.service`.  Pick the one you want and install it.